# ActiveXObject server http request fails with access is denied

Tags: javascript, iis-7

I am working with a website that uses JavaScript ASP files.  I am removing a call to a remote scripting object due to another problem that I cannot fix.  Instead, I am using an ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP") call to an ASMX web service.  I have tried calling the ASMX service inside the website and outside the website.  The calls work on my local computer using .  However, when I use the remote server to host the website, the call fails with "Access is denied".  This error is returned using a try/catch block around the HTTP request.  The site is using a self signed certificate.  The website has been able to ignore certificate errors on other calls.  This call is using the same code to ignore certificate errors.  However, all the other HTTP calls are made by using "Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP");".  "Server.CreateObject" is not available with my current change.  I have tried the remote server name and the IP address.  The error continues to be "Access is denied".  Eventually, this website will be using a certificate of authority and domain name.

I am out of ideas to try.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.